# Generating html pages off Django database entries

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to get a url mapping to follow this example

```
/user/user-name/list/list-name-goes-here
```

I created this regex (unsure if it's correct)

```
url(r'^user/(\w+)/list/(?P<listname>\w+)/$', mylistpage, name='lists'),
```

So users currently have the ability to insert a series of lists and they print onto their main profile page. I want them to click on the list and have it bring up a different html page with the list name as the header.
Lists can have spaces, so I need to slugify somehow.

I get this error currently:

```
mylistpage() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

## VIEW

```
def mylistpage(request, username, listname):

    context = RequestContext(request)

    if username == request.user.username:

        if request.user.is_authenticated():

            user = User.objects.get(username=username)

            listname = request.user.newlist_set.filter(list_name__startswirth=listname)

    return render_to_response('listview.html', {'lista': listname}, context)
```

## MODEL

```
class newlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100,)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles/', default = "/media/profiles/default.jpg")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to name both arguments in your regular expression:

```
url(r'^user/(?P<username>\w+)/list/(?P<listname>\w+)/$', mylistpage, name='lists'),
```

More on that on [Django documentation: URL Dispatcher: Named groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups).

Update: answering on the comments, to redirect to 404 if no `username` or `listname`, this would be handled in the view. For instance:

```
User.objects.get_object_or_404(username=username)
```

and

```
from django.http import Http404

if not listname:
    raise Http404("blah blah..")
```

Comment: If the user doesn't exist, how can I get it to 404?

Comment: This would be handled in the view: `user = User.objects.get_object_or_404(username=username)` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say if the listname doesn't exist!

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten to pass the username to the view:

```
url(r'^user/(?P<username>\w+)/list/(?P<listname>\w+)/$', mylistpage, name='lists'),
```